# Objects overwritten when other objects drawn

Tags: java, swing, object

I need to draw some objects to screen (rectangles, etc), but when `super.paint(g)` is called after drawing the rectangle, the rectangle isn't shown.

JPanels have been added.

This is my code:

```
    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

  super.paintComponent(g); 


  Color c1 = Color.white;
  g.setColor( c1 );
  g.drawLine( 50, 50, 325, 350 ); // start line
      //super.paint(g);

    g.dispose();
```

I've tried putting `super.paint(g);` before and after to no avail, the object I want to add isn't drawn.

Comment: `g.dispose();`  We should only dispose of a graphics object that we explicitly create.  This one is created by the JVM so we should not dispose it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(g)` method.
2. The first statement in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method should be `super.paintComponent(g)`. This will paint the background color of the component.
3. Then you do your custom painting.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.

> I'm new to java

Then I suggest you also look at the "trail" link from the above tutorial for a Table of Contents for the Swing basics.

Comment: Hi, I could not get super.paintComponent() to compile, I tried overriding but it never worked.I get the error: panel.java:41: error: cannot find symbol

panel.java:39: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: @user3560891: show your latest code as an edit to your original question. And note that the super method takes the same parameters as the overridden method -- pass the Graphics instance in there: `super.paintComponent(g)`. Also, be sure to place the `@Override` annotation at the top of your paintComponent override to make sure that you're overriding things correctly.

Comment: @user3560891, did you read the tutorial? Did you download the example program to see how it works? Did you read the API?

Comment: But you've not described what problems you're having with it. Also **never** dispose of a Graphics object that was given to you by the JVM. Sure dispose of Graphics objects that you create on your own, such as ones obtained from a BufferedImage, but not one passed to your paintComponent method, else you could have painting problems down-stream.

Comment: The code won't compile, the error I get is: panel.java:41: error: cannot find symbol

Comment: @user3560891, we have no idea what line 41 is. We have no idea what your code looks like. Read the tutorial and compare the code to see what the difference is. Start with working code and then make changes to the working code to do your custom painting. Learn by example.

Comment: Line 41 is the super.paintComponent(g)

Comment: @user3560891, That doesn't help. Without knowing the context of how that code is used in your class it doesn't help. Do some basic problem solving on your own. You've been given a link to a working program. Look at the code and understand how it works.